# Adding my own app to the share suggestions

Tags: javascript, android, ios, share, phonegap

Im currently writing a cross-platform app in phonegap. Its main purpose is to share information. E.g. you are watching a video on youtube and want to share it via my app. How can i add my own app to the suggestions that appear when you're pressing the share button?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15HmW.jpg (here's an image of what i mean)

The same question goes for other apps like soundcloud or something similiar (although i think that should be the same)

Thanks in Advance

-Abstract

Comment: You declare in your manifest that you support the ACTION_SHARE intent for that mime type.

Comment: Are you aware that YouTube now has chat? It's embedded into Android and iOS versions, so maybe you don't have to do anything else :)
Anyway, yeah, what @GabeSechan said, but I guess that's not an option with PhoneGap. Not sure this should even be tagged with Android or iOS

Comment: Does iOS support ACTION_SHARE? since im looking for a solution that works for both. But anyways thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS there are share extensions. They are a seperate target in your app and they allow you to take in photos, urls, or text as the input. Here is a link to the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1.